# layout objects in a curve lua corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, curve

I need a for loop in lua to layout rows of objects in  a curve instead of a straight line. How do you calculate the y co-ordinate as objects are positioned along curve? x co-ordinate is just the diameter of object * nr of columns plus the gap. But the y?

Is there a class that perhaps does this in corona? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no class for that, even because it is not needed! You only need to develop a mathematical function for it...

For example you might do:

```
object[index].x = initialX + gapX*index;
object[index].y = initialY + object[index].x^2
```

This will draw a parabolic curve :)